# Private Custom App Distribution Using ASM or ABM - Adding Another Organization

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval, iphone-developer-program

I am creating a custom app for private distribution to an organization that will use ASM to get it. I hope to be able to get a second organization once the first one is using it.

When submitting the app for review it allows for specifying which organization should have access to the App and I specify the first organization.

My question is how will it work once the app has been approved and now I would like to add the second organization. Will I have to go through another approval process for each organization I would like to make it available to?

Thanks